# Regridding operations on smaller subsets

Tags: netcdf, remap, cdo-climate

I have a NetCDF file, let's say only a portion of South America as shown below.
I want to use a `cdo` operation `remapnn` to remap the NetCDF file from 0.25x0.25 to 0.05x0.05 resolution. For that I use the code mentioned below, but the results are not what I expect it to be. Can someone provide some clarity to this?

```
#cdo version 1.9.3
export REMAP_EXTRAPOLATE='off'
cdo remapnn,r7200x3600 test.nc test2.nc
```

I always seem to have this problem when `remapping` a subset of a global map but works fine for the complete global map. It seems like `cdo` operation assumes that I am always working with a complete global map.

Link to the data is added [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/88dwseobtk0uh10/AACSVVrJEV0SvsCd2N0TXlu5a?dl=0).

[image]

Comment: just to point out that the "cdo" tag does not refer to climate data operators from MPI... that's why I had to create the cdo-climate tag

Comment: ps: It is a bit tricky to address this without access to the data file... do you have a link where we can download it to try it out?

Comment: @AdrianTompkins. Hi there. Now the data is available via the link mentioned in the post. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm, the first problem seems to be that the coords don't have any meta data at all and thus CDO for me fails with:  "Unsupported generic coordinates". If you don't want to add the metadata with nco, another option might be to try and remap with ncremap.  Not sure how you managed to get any output at all from cdo?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added a new file with generic co-ordinates. You can always use `ncatted -O -a units,lon,c,c,"degrees_east" -a units,lat,a,c,"degrees_north" test.nc` to add metadata.

Comment: so that isn't the file you made your test on when you posed the question?

Comment: I actually wrote a shell script with the metadata (including the one in the question and one in the comment above), but I did not add the whole script. Sorry about that.